# Добавление php кода в тело addScriptDeclaration

Tags: php, javascript, joomla, joomla3

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как добавить вывод php кода в тело addScriptDeclaration?

Есть такой код (просто его часть):

```
<?php

  $document->addScriptDeclaration('
    $("#address_street").suggestions({
    token: "0000000000000000000000",
    type: "ADDRESS",
    onSelect: showPostalCode,
    onSelectNothing: clearPostalCode
    });
  ');

?>
```

Как вместо **0000000000000000000000** вставить вывод php кода, например, **$plg_params->get('allow')**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разобрался: необходимо использовать вот такую конструкцию:

```
token: "' . $plg_params->get('token') . '"
```